# Как вычислить разницу между строками в фрейме данных?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, nan

Есть фрейм данных с данными об аффилиатах, офферах, кликах и т.д.

Я хочу посчитать разницу в конверсиях (столбец `Appr`) между вчерашним и сегодняшним днем по каждому офферу + аффилиату, и добавить разницу в столбец `DiffAppr`.

Исходный фрейм данных выглядит так:

```
| D  | H  | AfID | Affil_name | M     | OfID | Offer_name  | Clicks | Revenue | Earnings | Appr | Decl | CR    | Tr-back |
|----|----|------|------------|-------|------|-------------|--------|---------|----------|------|------|-------|---------|
| 28 | 11 | 340  | alex       |  T    | 2132 | FlashPlaye  | 10000  | 0       | 0        | 100  | 0    | 1:100 | 0       |
| 29 | 11 | 528  | ido        | Marti | 2587 | Amazon_S    | 20400  | 0       | 0        | 68   | 0    | 1:300 | 0       |
| 29 | 11 | 340  | alex       |  T    | 2132 | FlashPlayer | 2800   | 3       | 0,6      | 200  | 0    | 1:14  | 0       |
```

Я применяю функцию `diff()` + `groupby()`:

```
df['Diff'] = df.groupby(['H', 'AfID', 'Affil_name', 'M', 'OfID','Offer_name'])['Appr'].diff().fillna(0)
```

Результат такой:

```
|  D |  H | AfID | Affil_name |   M   | OfID | Offer_name | Clicks | Revenue | Earnings | Appr | Decl |   CR  | Tr-back | Diff |
|:--:|:--:|:----:|:----------:|:-----:|:----:|:----------:|:------:|:-------:|:--------:|:----:|:----:|:-----:|:-------:|:----:|
| 28 | 11 | 340  | alex       |  T    | 2132 | FlashPlaye | 10000  | 0       | 0        | 100  | 0    | 1:100 | 0       | 0    |
| 29 | 11 | 528  | ido        | Marti | 2587 | Amazon_S   | 20400  | 0       | 0        | 68   | 0    | 1:300 | 0       | 0    |
| 29 | 11 | 340  | alex       |  T    | 2132 | FlashPlaye | 10000  | 0       | 0        | 200  | 0    | 1:100 | 0       | 100  |
```

Т.е., если в фрейме данных нет данных за предыдущий день по этому офферу+аффилиату (2 строка), то эта строка игнорируется и не вычисляется, хотя за сегодняшний день Appr=68, значит в `DiffAppr` должно быть 68.

Как могу это сделать?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, хотя бы часть исходного датафрейма в воспроизводимом формате.

Comment: С другой стороны, что мешает вам _сначала_ сделать `df["Appr"].fillna(0, inplace=True)`, а затем уже группировку и `diff`,

Comment: @strawdog, а зачем _сначала_ заполнять `NaN`, если их сначала нет и что это даст?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]:
    D   H  AfID Affil_name      M  OfID   Offer_name  Clicks  Revenue Earnings  Appr  Decl     CR  Tr-back
0  28  11   340       alex      T  2132  FlashPlayer   10000        0        0   100     0  1:100        0
1  29  11   528        ido  Marti  2587     Amazon_S   20400        0        0    68     0  1:300        0
2  29  11   340       alex      T  2132  FlashPlayer    2800        3      0,6   200     0   1:14        0
```

Решение:

```
idx = df.reset_index().groupby(['H', 'AfID', 'Affil_name', 'M', 'OfID','Offer_name'])["index"].last().to_numpy()

df['Diff'] = df.groupby(['H', 'AfID', 'Affil_name', 'M', 'OfID','Offer_name'])['Appr'].diff()

df.loc[idx, "Diff"] = df.loc[idx, "Diff"].combine_first(df.loc[idx, "Appr"])
```

Результат:

```
In [47]: df
Out[47]:
    D   H  AfID Affil_name      M  OfID   Offer_name  Clicks  Revenue Earnings  Appr  Decl     CR  Tr-back   Diff
0  28  11   340       alex      T  2132  FlashPlayer   10000        0        0   100     0  1:100        0    NaN
1  29  11   528        ido  Marti  2587     Amazon_S   20400        0        0    68     0  1:300        0   68.0
2  29  11   340       alex      T  2132  FlashPlayer    2800        3      0,6   200     0   1:14        0  100.0
```

Comment: Сработало, спасибо